# Link to Appendix (from anywhere in the document) goes to the wrong place.

Tags: hyperref, links

I have several chapters and several appendices. I am using the hyperref package, and everything is numbered (all the chapters, appendices, etc...) My appendices also have sections within them and I refer to those sections in the text.

All the links to the appendices or anywhere in them go to the wrong place. For example, my toc links to appendix 1 go to chapter 1, not appendix 1. Links to appendix 2 go to chapter 2, etc... Also, links to sections within an appendix go to a random page in the chapter in the document (not to the appendix).

This is somewhat urgent so any help is greatly appreciated.

If I can't make the links work, is there a way to disable the linking just for appendices? Links work fine all over the document otherwise.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.  Otherwise we have to guess as to what is going wrong.

Comment: Just before your `\appendix`, add `\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{A\arabic{chapter}}`, which should update the way [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) sees a link to a chapter. These should cascade down to `\section`s as well (just a guess)... It all depends on your `\documentclass` and the way you construct your appendices.

Comment: Thank you so much! adding that command before \appendix did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

And use

```
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{A\arabic{section}}
```

if you have the same trouble with the article class. For more information, the `hyperref` [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) explains how hyperref modifies important LaTeX counters (sections, chapter, ...) into `\theH<counter>` for referencing.

Comment: ... You put this just before your first appendix's \section{}